# To build the Iron Man suit, what fields did Tony Stark need to be an expert in?

Tags: iron-man, marvel, science

I have been thinking about superheroes lately and Iron Man seems to be the safest one. His suit allows him to practically be bulletproof.

**In what fields did Tony Stark have to be an expert in to build the Iron Man suits (aside from being extremely rich and being an amazingly successful entrepreneur)?**

Comment: I suppose it's possible that there's an explanation in the comics of exactly what fields Tony had to be skilled in to build this, but otherwise, I feel like this is a request for a real-world explanation of a fantastical element.

Comment: @aideendoyle - /Sigh. *Please* don't use the comments box to answer off-topic questions. It just encourages people to ask them rather than improving the question.

Comment: I had to think about it before I did it but due to the fact there is no real world technology that could replicate Tony Stark's work this is not a real world question. "Questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction." The question might seem like a real world question but it fits the criteria for the very thing it's being put on hold for - it is a solution for a cited work of fiction and is not currently real world possible. /shrugs Seems on topic to me so I tried.

Comment: Doesn't the question in fact "relate directly to a cited work of fiction"? If people interpret that rule to be saying that questions about real scientific solutions are *never* allowed, why do you think the rule includes that qualification?

Comment: He had to be an expert in the field of Combat Exosuits.

Comment: 1. Iron. 2. Suits. 3. Men.

Answer (score 22):

Off the top of my head (and relating the answer to the films, rather than the comics) there were a number of fields in which Tony Stark demonstrated outstanding knowledge

### Engineering + Physics

Tony's arc reactor, the literal heart of the machine is a [wonder of engineering](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36098/how-does-iron-mans-arc-reactor-work), outputting a vast amount of electricity with no obvious source of fuel, potentially a form of fusion(?) and definitely containing plasma and magnetics.

[image]

Alongside this, he creates a workable augmented suit of armour, something that the finest minds at DARPA have [struggled with for a generation](http://www.kurzweilai.net/darpas-human-augmentation-suit)

### Flight Dynamics and Rocketry

Let's not brush aside the fact that Tony's suit can fly on tiny little jets that have no evident source of fuel. The output from those much be absolutely fabulous to lift a suit weighing [the best part of a metric ton](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52427/is-iron-man-s-suit-really-heavy-enough-to-break-through-his-roof/52438#52438)

[image]

Oh, and the suit appears to have some sort of g-damping technology that allows him to slam into walls and not die.

### Weapons design

The suit has built in weaponry including rockets, modified guns, heat-seeking trackers, etc etc. At the very minimum, Tony would have to have an expert knowledge in how to make, maintain and install these weapons in order to have not killed himself many times over

[image]

### AI + Computing

Tony's suit contains a realtime AI. An AI. Let's think about that for a second. A fully functional, turing-compliant Artificial Intelligence lives in the memory of his suit and can, apparently communicate with him in total realtime, organising his diary, arranging comms with third parties, planning routes, determining strategy and keeping an eye on radar.

Of all of his inventions, this one is the most epic.

[image]

### Metallurgy and Armour Design

The armour on the suit is, as you've pointed out, completely bulletproof and regularly takes hits from uber-powered weapons and energy beams. The fact that it doesn't even come off dented would suggest a knowledge of ultra-light, ultra-strong alloys.

### Bionics, Life Sciences and Medical

Tony's suit appears to be able to read his mind, assess his health (in realtime) and provide medical assistance when required. At the very least, he must have a full working knowledge of Neuroscience, anatomy, physiology and trauma medicine in order to have accomplished the feats we see in the films.

Comment: Great answer to a less than stellar question, +1

Comment: _"The fact that it doesn't even come off dented"_ Ehm..

Comment: Anyway, so, in short, Tony's a genius and a world authority on just about everything.

Comment: If it weren't for the scene in the cave, I would offer the suggestion that he only *needed* to be an expert in AI, and then JARVIS could have designed the rest.

Comment: "when did you become an expert in thermonuclear astrophysics"? tony:"last night"

Comment: When flying in an atmosphere, the suit jets presumably heat air.  Like a jet engine, they use air as reaction mass to push against.  It's only operation in space where carrying your own supply of reaction mass becomes an issue.

Comment: The problem is that no matter how much a genius he is, an AI like Jarvis probably requires millions of lines of code. When did he find the time to develop it?

Comment: @vsz - I'm guessing that there's more than just Tony working in that enormous building of his.

Answer (score 0):

In wikipedia, it says that Tony is an inventive genius whos expertise in the fields of mathematics, physics, chemistry, and computer science rivals that on Hank Pym, Bruce Banner, and Mister Fantastic, and his expertise in electrical and mechanical engineering surpasses even theirs. So ya. But that is for the comic-book Iron Man, so lets delve into the movie one. It says on the Marvel Cinematic Universe fandom that Tony has expertise in many fields of science, particularly physics, but also chemistry, computer science, and neuroscience, and is also a genius engineer and robotics technician. But i totally agree with that awnser above that got 22 votes. cool.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you're going to cite information from Wikipedia though, or any other website, you should ideally include a direct quote, and a link to the relevant page. Also, since Wikipedia isn't an official source, and can be edited by anyone at any time, it isn't considered a very reliable source anyway. Information sourced directly from the comics, movies, or handbooks would be much more persuasive.